# Copying files using a manifest as reference

Tags: file, shell, copy, directory

I need to move a bunch of files in the /data/files directory to a new folder structure. In the /data directory, I have a manifest file that contains the full working path of each file.

Source Files:

```
/data/files/this_file_1.sh
/data/files/this_file_2.sh
```

Manifest File Contains:

```
/path/to/where/file/goes/this_file_1.sh
/a/different/path/to/file/this_file_2.sh
```

I need help writing a shell script that will find the filename in the manifest and run a copy command. If the directory structure doesn't exist, create it.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file_name in $(cat manifest); do
  name=$(basename $file_name);
  path= ??

  # Mkdir / Copy

done
```

1. How can I get the filename from the full path of the file?
2. How can I create the directories prior to copying the files?

Comment: help mean: _make it easier for (someone) to do something_. That's not the same: _doing the whole work instead of his_. please read [ask].

Comment: I know the definition of help. I'm asking for help - references or pointers in how to do something so I can write the script myself. Not expecting someone to write in detail everything. I'm not familiar in how to read a file in shell and grab the filename from the full path to be able to put it into an array so I can run a copy command on each file.

Comment: I think `path` would be equal to `file_name`

Comment: So I'm able to get the file name, how can I get the path without the file name now?   path=$file_name gives me the full path with file name at the end.

Comment: `dirname` in case you didn't see my other comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to let you write the full script, but here are some commands you could use:

"Find the filename in the manifest" - `basename filepath`

"Verify it exists in /data/files" - `if [ -e filename ]; then ......`

"Run a copy command" - `cp location1 location2`

"If the directory structure doesn't exist, create it" - `else mkdir /data/files` or whatever the directory you want to create is.

If you have any questions about these commands leave a comment :-)

Comment: I want to be able to copy all the files in the manifest. So using grep wouldn't be useful. The files would already exist as the manifest is created after the files have been written.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You want to extract filenames from an existing manifest no? Where would grep fall short? 

edit: after you updated your question, I believe I understand

Comment: Wouldn't I need to know the name of the file to use grep? I need to parse out the file name from the full path of the file.

Comment: Yes, I will modify my answer to reflect this

Comment: So I can get the filename from file_name(base_name ) but I guess the part I need help is reading the manifest, putting each line in an array, and being able to parse out the file_name from each item in the array.

Comment: if the manifest only consists of filenames you can do `for item in manifest; do; basename .......; done`.
Otherwise, you can do `grep *.sh` or whatever you expect the extension to be. You do not need to use arrays

Comment: Ok, got that taken care of. I'm able to list all the file names without the path, and check if they exist or not in their target locations. I just need to extract the path without the filename to use the mkdir command

Comment: awesome! `dirname` does what you suggested. Kind of like the opposite of `basename`.